# Suddenly receiving UNKNOWN_ERROR on maps/api/geocode server-side requests

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

Our server uses the Google Maps API probably a few dozen times a day to turn street addresses into lat/lng coordinates, for later use on a client-side google map.

We've been doing this for years, and we're hitting this URL to do it:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=<street address>&sensor=false
```

We do this from a Perl script, and it runs once every 15 minutes, processing any that have queued up (again, we're talking a couple dozen requests a DAY). If multiple are queued, it hits the API serially in bursts of 5, then pauses 5 seconds before continuing, if any more remain.

This has worked fine for years now.

Today, we have started regularly receiving HTTP 500 response code, with this JSON in the body:

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
}
```

I have taken one of the actual requests, and repeatedly hit it from my local dev box, and it works fine (repeatedly).

Yet on our server (colocated at a major service provider), I repeat the test, and I can regularly duplicate the 500 error in the browser.

Both my dev box and our server are currently resolving maps.googleapis.com to the same IP:

```
googleapis.l.google.com [74.125.198.95]
```

So I don't think it's an issue of our server hitting a bad Google server.

I would suspect a quota issue, except our use is very, very minimal. Perhaps they are blocking a large swath of RackSpace customers, but no idea how we could find this out or rectify it if so.

After further testing on other servers we have colocated at the same facility, only a single server is exhibiting this issue, though the other servers are in different network class entirely.

Does Google typically use this kind of error message for quota issues? If not, any other ideas as to what the problem is, so we can fix it? At this point, we may need to switch to Bing Maps or some other provider, if there's no way to know why it's happening, or when it will return to normal.

I checked [Google's status page](http://www.google.com/appsstatus), and "Google Maps" is green with no issues indicated, but I have no idea if this considers their Maps API services or not.

Comment: Just ran your URL from my browser (with a valid address), I didn't get an error.  Is this only from your server?

Comment: “I have taken one of the actual requests, and repeatedly hit it from my local dev box, and it works fine (repeatedly).

Yet on our server (colocated at a major service provider), I repeat the test, and I can regularly duplicate the 500 error in the browser.”

Comment: I have the exact scenario. Have you managed to find a solution for that?

Comment: @Noam I believe the issue turned out to be one of our devs accidentally including the "bleeding edge" JS version of Google Maps, rather than using the latest stable version. So I think we guessed that we were seeing the odd behavior due to that.

Comment: Um, how come [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) affected [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)? The first one is to be used on client, the latter, on server. Including older version Google Maps Javascript API make it stop receiving this errors? I received this error today after doing 2000 or so requests. I believe that must be an error occurring occasionally and you just have to redo the request.

Comment: Well, 10 attempts with 1 sec delay between them hasn't helped me just now. But after I noticed it and redo the request it finished without UNKNOWN_ERROR.

Comment: I see this occasionally (once every other day or so) on an app that does a few thousand geocodes per day. No rhyme or reason AFAICT; the addresses are perfectly valid and retrying later (after seeing the issue) often returns a correct result.

Comment: I see this occasionally (once every other day or so) on an app that does a few thousand geocodes per day. No rhyme or reason AFAICT; the addresses are perfectly valid and retrying later (after seeing the issue) often returns a correct result.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti have you found any solution for this?